# Allowable format for webworker data transfer

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I've been looking at how to transfer data to and from webworkers, and every example I've found has shown the following format:

```
var myData = new Uint8ClampedArray(256);
postMessage(myData.buffer, [ myData.buffer ]);
```

However I'd like to be able to send additional data. So, my question is does the following also transfer ownership of `myData`'s buffer, or is it just copying?

```
var myData = new Uint8ClampedArray(256);
postMessage({ foo: 'bar', data: myData }, [ myData.buffer ]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just returned to this after a couple months, and decided to run a benchmark. Unfortunately I couldn't figure out how to do it properly on jsperf, so I went ahead and put [this gist](https://gist.github.com/grind086/47cd2bb5c8a3ff5877962a88a774dbd3) together. Using a 1 MB `Uint8ClampedArray` over 10000 round-trip loops, my results were as follows:

```
worker.postMessage(data, [ data.buffer ]);
// => 1112ms

worker.postMessage({ foo: 'bar', data: data }, [ data.buffer ]);
// => 1220ms

worker.postMessage(data);
// => 11862ms

worker.postMessage({ foo: 'bar', data: data });
// => 12244ms
```

The results were basically what I expected, but it's nice to have confirmation. There does appear to be some overhead (~10%) with adding extra data in an object, but array buffer ownership is transferred properly.